# Proof that $ (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z},+) /\langle(2,3)\rangle $ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I need a little help with the second half of the proof that $ (\mathbb{Z}  \times \mathbb{Z},+) / \langle(2,3)\rangle $ is cyclic.

I know isomorphism preserves cyclic structure.I looked up the answer on my textbook from where I got this exercise and their proof is like this:

"The function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}  \times \mathbb{Z} /\langle(2,3)\rangle$ with $f(x) = \widehat{(x,x)}$ is an isomorphism of groups because :

- $(x,x)$ is not in $\langle(2,3)\rangle$ for every $x \neq 0$.
- $(a,b) =(b-a)(2,3)+(3a-2b)(1,1)$ for a,b in $\mathbb{Z}$ .

I think in the first part they try to show that the function is injective but I don't understand the second part,can someone explain it to me?
 Thanks alot !

Comment: The second part is about showing surjectivity : any $(a,b)$ is equivalent (mod $\langle (2,3) \rangle$ ) to $(3a-2b) \cdot (1,1)$, which is in the image of $f$ (it's $f(3a-2b)$). Therefore every residue class mod $\langle (2,3) \rangle$ is in the image of $f$ : $f$ is surjective

Comment: Damn,thank you , now I understand, wasn't hard at all :\ .

Comment: For $k=gcd(m,n)=1$ we have $(\mathbb{Z}\times  \mathbb{Z})/\langle (m,n)\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}$.